# Uber API retrieve driver history

Tags: uber-api

on Uber developer documentation i have seen that is possible to retrieve the histroy trip about user.
Is possible to retrieve the list of driver trip with start city and end city into response?

Comment: Please check Driver API Uber documentation - and endpoint [GET /partners/trips](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-trips-get)

Comment: Hi Sasa, thanks for your replay. I have seen this endpoint but by documentation I have seen that response show only the start city without end city so in this way I can’t see the all route trip. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /trips endpoint with the Driver API is essentially /history for drivers. You are correct that this does not include end city, just the start city: https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-trips-get

So if you need the destination location for Driver history, that is currently not possible with Driver API. Thanks for the request, but no changes imminent there.